# Paypal One-Click Purchase

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, paypal, payment-processing

Is it possible to implement One-Click Purchase using Paypal API? or Paypal Adaptive API? Instead of asking the user to login each and every time.

Thanks in advance.

Johnny

Comment: I think this would potentially breach security, im some cases? It may be possible but would probably require some trusted certificates or other security measures before allowing it.

Comment: I was thinking along the same line, looking at all the major payment gateways, they all require you to direct to their site to do the actual payment, I assume for security reason. But Amazon do have this thing called multi use token, which allows One-Click Purchase. I was wondering if Paypal has similar thing.

Answer (score 3):

To have a  "one click checkout" experience with Paypal, solution is the "Preapproved Payments Flow" from the [Adaptive payment](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro).

The following diagram shows the basic flow of control during a [preapproval operation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/images/developer/AdapPymntSrvcFlow_B.gif).

After the sender sets up the approval, you can make payments on the sender’s behalf directly. The sender is no longer required to log in to PayPal to complete the payment.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.x.com/message/185849

I don't think that is the way you are looking to do it but it's the only way PayPal's API will allow it.

Answer (score 1):

that's correct Adaptive Payments Preapproval API is the best way to do this: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/how-to-guides/how-set-payment-preapproval-using-adaptive-payments

You could also use the Reference Transaction APIs too - you can find the how-tos for those here:

- [Cards](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/how-to-guides/how-run-reference-transaction-using-direct-payment)
- [PayPal Accounts](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/how-to-guides/how-set-reference-transaction-using-express-checkout)

Answer (score 0):

Check this ! It's 1,5 years later now an PayPal has improved quite much: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_buynow_buttons