# Paypal True One Click Upsell

Tags: php, api, paypal, oneclick

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206808/paypal-one-click-purchase), but it was asked 6 years ago.
So, I want to know is there a way to implement a true click upsell with paypal. I mean we have to redirect users every time and make them login and sign the agreement.
Is there any way that users only need to login once and when they return to our site (e.g. on the upsell page of the funnel) then they just click buy button and we can charge them without redirecting to paypal's site.

Comment: why not do the upsell before payment? i see many sites suggest product combos on the product page itself.

Comment: yes that's an other option.. but we can't bind our customers to this scenario.. there could be different possible scenarios...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options for this.

1)  Express Checkout Billing Agreements + Reference Transactions.  This documentation outlines those procedures:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ec_set_up_reference_transactions/

2)  PayPal Identity APIs - Login with PayPal + Seamless Checkout.  This documentation covers those procedures:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/

I would recommend you take a look at our [PayPal PHP SDK class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) as it will make the API calls required to get this done very quick and easy.

Comment: okay i will look into these options in detail and then will accept your answer ...

Comment: it appears that reference transactions will do the task.

Comment: @JunaidAhmad and @andrew-angell I see on top of the first link that it says `Important: This integration method is Deprecated as of January 1, 2017. For new integrations, see the PayPal Express Checkout Integration Guide.`. I have this same request from my client to implement it for the upsell after regular checkup. @JunaidAhmad do you use this integration even today or it's not working? thank you.

Comment: PayPal is trying to move things into the REST APIs as much as possible, so they've started to label the Classic APIs as deprecated.  They will not be going away, though, and they will continue to fix any bugs that come up on them.  I still use them heavily myself.  That said, the REST API does support "billing plans" and "billing agreements" so you can accomplish the same sort of thing that way.

Comment: No, we didn't implemented the solution. Sorry, couldn't help you anymore.